# How do you render the grails 404 GSON template with the rest-api profile with the gsp dependency added

Tags: grails, urlmappings.groovy

I have built a grails 4.0.10 app with the rest-profile.

Then added the console plugin. (because it is just too handy)
`compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.1.1'`

Which has a dependency on gsps.
`compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"  // console plugin needs to render gsps.`

Once the gsp plugin is added, the 404 handler now renders a default notFound.gsp instead of the notFound.gson file.

Is there a way to set up URL mappings to render the .gson view by default instead of the .gsp one?

The only mechanism I found was to create an error controller to handle it manually,  but I feel like i'm overlooking something really simple in UrlMappings.

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        ...
        "404"(controller: "error", action:'notFound')
    }
}
```

and then creating an errorController to render the view.

```
class ErrorController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    
    def notFound() {
        render(view: "/notFound")
    }
}
```

Here is hoping for   `"404"(view: '/notFound', pleaseUseGson: true)` setting that I haven't found.

Comment: Do you really need the `notFound.gsp` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is getting confused because there is a notFound.gsp entry hidden in the cache plugin.

the views.properties file has this line

`/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/notFound.gsp=gsp_cachenotFound_gsp`

I'm not entirely sure why this view from the cache plugin is being used before the one in my app, but that's a problem for later.

By renaming the notfound.gson file to something else seems to circumvent the problem.

so change

`"404"(view: '/notFound')`

to

`"404"(view: '/notFound404')`

and rename the file notFound.gson to notFound404.gson.